# Blocked threads due to long running connection?

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

Every now and then an old Java I have to maintain stops responding. I managed to get a couple of thread stack traces and most threads are blocked like this trying to obtain a connection:

```
"tomcat-http-8180-168" - Thread t@10137
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.retrieveCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:566)
    - waiting to lock <566080> (a oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache) owned by "Thread-6" t@29
```

The thread holding the lock shows this:

```
"Thread-6" - Thread t@29
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.closeLogicalConnection(PhysicalConnection.java:3849)
    - waiting to lock <146da30> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection) owned by "tomcat-http-8180-369" t@17665
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection.cleanupAndClose(LogicalConnection.java:304)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.closeCheckedOutConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:1392)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCacheThread.runAbandonedTimeout(OracleImplicitConnectionCacheThread.java:250)
    - locked <566080> (a oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCacheThread.run(OracleImplicitConnectionCacheThread.java:81)
```

This thread seems to be responsible for closing abandoned connections, and it's itself blocked waiting for this other thread to finish:

```
"tomcat-http-8180-369" - Thread t@17665
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:282)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:230)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:122)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:78)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readB1(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:149)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.buffer2Value(T4CMAREngine.java:2393)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB8(T4CMAREngine.java:1401)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTILob.readRPA(T4C8TTILob.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:292)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIClob.read(T4C8TTIClob.java:240)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getChars(T4CConnection.java:3015)
    - locked <146da30> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
    at oracle.sql.CLOB.getChars(CLOB.java:402)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleClobReader.needChars(OracleClobReader.java:187)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleClobReader.read(OracleClobReader.java:142)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.ClobAccessor.getString(ClobAccessor.java:291)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CClobAccessor.getString(T4CClobAccessor.java:481)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getString(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1251)
    - locked <146da30> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:494)
```

This last thread is running a heavy query. Which is also why it's considered abandoned and Tomcat is trying to close it but it seemingly can't as it's in use and has a lock.

I don't understand why:

- Oracle can't close the connection.
- The other threads can't get a connection from the pool until the abandoned connection is closed.

Because by looking at the thread stack above it's what's happening. When the extra-long query finished (I know I have to look into that query) then the app started responding again as the threads unblocked.

This is Tomcat's (v6) pool config (sensitive details ommitted):

```
<Resource
        name="jdbc/MainDBPool"
        AutoCommit="true"
        defaultReadOnly="false"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
        fairQueue="false"
        initialSize="10"
        jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState;StatementFinalizer"
        jmxEnabled="true"
        logAbandoned="false"
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="75"
        maxWait="30000"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="5000"
        minIdle="10"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
        testOnBorrow="false"
        testOnReturn="false"
        testWhileIdle="false"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000"
        type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
        connectionCachingEnabled="true"
        connectionCacheName="tomcatConnectionCache1"
        fastConnectionFailoverEnabled="true"
        implicitCachingEnabled="true"
        connectionCacheProperties="(ValidateConnection=true, PropertyCheckInterval=60, AbandonedConnectionTimeout=300, InitialLimit=10, MinLimit=30, MaxLimit=200, ConnectionWaitTimeout=30, InactivityTimeout=300)"
        useEquals="false"
        validationInterval="30000"
        />
```

I also looked into other possible causes, like a long full GC, but GC logging was enabled and there isn't a long pause that would explain this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Implicit Connection Cache is desupported.  You must use Universal Connection Pool (UCP) which is the ICC's replacement.  You can download [ucp.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html) and check out ["UCP with Tomcat"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/planned-unplanned-rlb-ucp-tomcat-2265175.pdf) whitepaper for more details.